# If the average of a sequence converges, does the average of the square roots converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, average

I'm looking for a nice proof or counterexample for the following claim:

If $d_i \in [0,1]$ are such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (d_1+...+d_n)/n$ is well-defined, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt{d_1}+...+\sqrt{d_n})/n$ is well-defined.

Comment: You should be suspicious of this, since if $d_i\in (0,1)$ then $\sqrt{d_i}>d_i$. So a counterexample seems like the right bet...

Comment: But if $d_i \in (0,1)$, then the averages of square roots is bounded by 1 still, so summability is not the issue here, @Semiclassical

Comment: You're right. I had in mind the (divergent) sum of reciprocal integers versus the (convergent) sum of reciprocal squares. But the averages converge to zero just fine. @WillieWong

Comment: that said, I think your comment is still on the right track, probably. Let me see if I can cook up a counterexample. @Semiclassical

Comment: $0 + 1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$, but $\sqrt{0} + \sqrt{1} < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$. Alternate between runs of $0,1,0,1,\dotsc$ and $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \dotsc$.

Comment: @DanielFischer you beat me to it. Make it an answer?

Comment: Sorry for the flawed "proof"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $(2k)! \leqslant n < (2k+1)!$, let $d_n = \frac{1}{2}$, and for $(2k+1)! \leqslant n < (2k+2)!$ let $d_n = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(1 + (-1)^n\bigr)$.

Then we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m = 1}^n d_m = \frac{1}{2},$$

but

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(2k)!}\sum_{m = 1}^{(2k)!} \sqrt{d_m} &\leqslant \frac{(2k-1)! + \frac{2k-1}{2}(2k-1)!}{(2k)!},\\
\frac{1}{(2k+1)!}\sum_{m = 1}^{(2k+1)!} \sqrt{d_m} &\geqslant \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}2k(2k)!}{(2k+1)!},
\end{align}

so

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m = 1}^n \sqrt{d_m} \leqslant \frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m = 1}^n \sqrt{d_m}.$$